# Using Lambda on binary_search and replace_if

Tags: c++, visual-c++, std

I have been trying to get this to where binary_search would answer the if statement as true or false. I have not had problems with that in the past, however I am having issues getting it to search the tempStr in the struct I have made up. What I am trying to achieve with binary_search is for it to say whether the product exists or not, and make the decision whether to even bother doing a for loop or not to actually go out and get the name of the product. I get errors when I execute, and I do not understand why.

The second issue I have incurred is that I want to replace the price that is already in the vector with one that the user inputs, however this incurs similar errors to that of the binary_search. This is something I had made in my naïve attempt to make this happen, any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Will clarify if I am asked to do so.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct grocery{
    string name;
    string expdate;
    string price;
};

int main(){
    grocery tempProd;
    string tempStr;
    vector<grocery> produce;
    
    cout << "What grocery product are you looking for?";
    getline(cin, tempStr);
    if(binary_search(produce.begin(), produce.end(), [&] (const grocery &p) {return p.name == tempStr;})){
        cout << "Product has been found!" << endl;
        for(int i= 0; i<produce.size(); i++){
            if(produce[i].name == tempStr){
                string tempStr2;
                cout << "What is going to be the new price of the product?";
                getline(cin, tempStr2);
                replace_if(produce.begin(), produce.end(), produce[i].price,
                    [&] (const grocery &p) {return p.price == tempStr2;});

            }
        }
        
    }
    else{
        cout << "Product does not exist." << endl;
    }
}
```

I have mainly messed about with lambda for this, however it has not brought me much, if any success. Pointers also seemed like they would be the answer to me, but that did not do me much good either, and I just seem to find myself back here, at this location.

Here is how the struct is set up, and how the vector is set up since I know both of those are important.

***Errors***

```
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'bool std::binary_search(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<body*, std::vector<body> >; _Tp = main()::<lambda(const body&)>]':
teste.cpp:45:117:   required from here
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' and 'body')
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:64,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:454:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)'      
  454 |     operator<(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_pair.h:454:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:331:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)'
  331 |     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:331:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:369:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)'
  369 |     operator<(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:369:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:1163:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)'
 1163 |     operator<(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:1163:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:1169:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>&)'
 1169 |     operator<(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:1169:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_IteratorL>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\string:55,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6226:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)'
 6226 |     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6226:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\string:55,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6239:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)'
 6239 |     operator<(const basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6239:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\string:55,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\locale_classes.h:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:41,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6251:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)'
 6251 |     operator<(const _CharT* __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\basic_string.h:6251:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'main()::<lambda(const body&)>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\ios_base.h:46,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:42,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\system_error:208:3: note: candidate: 'bool std::operator<(const std::error_code&, const std::error_code&)'
  208 |   operator<(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |   ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\system_error:208:31: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' to 'const std::error_code&'
  208 |   operator<(const error_code& __lhs, const error_code& __rhs) noexcept
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\system_error:282:3: note: candidate: 'bool std::operator<(const std::error_condition&, const std::error_condition&)'
  282 |   operator<(const error_condition& __lhs,
      |   ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\system_error:282:36: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' to 'const std::error_condition&'
  282 |   operator<(const error_condition& __lhs,
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\vector:67,
                 from teste.cpp:3:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1905:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)' 1905 |     operator<(const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __x, const vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& __y)
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_vector.h:1905:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\algorithm:62,
                 from teste.cpp:5:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2259:39: note:   'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' is not derived from 'const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>'
 2259 |       return __i != __last && !(__val < *__i);
      |                                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void std::replace_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<body*, std::vector<body> >; _Predicate = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = main()::<lambda(const body&)>]':
teste.cpp:53:82:   required from here
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4401:12: error: no match for call to '(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>) (body&)'
 4401 |  if (__pred(*__first))
      |      ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4402:13: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'body' and 'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>')
 4402 |    *__first = __new_value;
      |    ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
teste.cpp:9:8: note: candidate: 'body& body::operator=(const body&)'
    9 | struct body{
      |        ^~~~
teste.cpp:9:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' to 'const body&'
teste.cpp:9:8: note: candidate: 'body& body::operator=(body&&)'
teste.cpp:9:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>' to 'body&&'
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_val::operator()(_Iterator, _Value&) const [with _Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<body*, std::vector<body> >; _Value = const main()::<lambda(const body&)>]':
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:979:14:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__lower_bound(_ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, const _Tp&, _Compare) [with _ForwardIterator = 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<body*, std::vector<body> >; _Tp = main()::<lambda(const body&)>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_val]'
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:2257:22:   required from 'bool std::binary_search(_FIter, _FIter, const _Tp&) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<body*, std::vector<body> >; _Tp = main()::<lambda(const body&)>]'
teste.cpp:45:117:   required from here
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:65:22: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 'body' and 'const main()::<lambda(const body&)>')
   65 |       { return *__it < __val; }
      |                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:915:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator<(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorR, _Container>&)'
  915 |     operator<(const __normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:915:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:65:22: note:   'body' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_IteratorL, _Container>'
   65 |       { return *__it < __val; }
      |                ~~~~~~^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:67,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:922:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _Iterator, class _Container> bool __gnu_cxx::operator<(const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&, const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>&)'
  922 |     operator<(const __normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __lhs,
      |     ^~~~~~~~
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_iterator.h:922:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algobase.h:71,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:39,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from teste.cpp:1:
c:\cpp\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\bits\predefined_ops.h:65:22: note:   'body' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>'
   65 |       { return *__it < __val; }
```

edit: yes I know the example doesn't have a grocery yet, but having a grocery or not has NOT caused a problem, as I am working with information from a text file, this is literally the bare minimum that causes the issues I am getting.

Comment: _I get errors when I execute_ What errors please?  Also, we need a [mcve].

Comment: the minimum reproducible example has been provided, as well as the errors I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the compiler error relating to `binary_search` is fixed (which is a bit tricky, since `binary_search` searches for a `grocery` and not a `string`), it won't help you.  That is because `binary_search` requires the vector to be sorted to work correctly and it isn't, here.

Therefore, replace it with [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), which does not have this requirement:

```
auto it = std::find_if (produce.begin(), produce.end(), [&] (const grocery &g) {return g.name == tempStr;});
```

Doing that means that you don't then need to search the vector again for the matching item since you already have an iterator pointing right at it.  Instead, you can just do:

```
if (it != produce.end()){
    cout << "Product has been found!" << endl;
    cout << "What is going to be the new price of the product?";
    string tempStr2;
    getline(cin, tempStr2);
    it->price = tempStr2;
}
else{
    cout << "Product does not exist." << endl;
}
```

All in all, a better solution.

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/7f091K)

Comment: Thank you man! I tried some stuff with `find_if`` earlier and nothing seemed to work, which is why I tried to replace it with a for loop to begin with, thank you very much!